# Where can I get the instagram shortcode from this url

Tags: instagram-api

I have been using the Instagram API for some time, but I see a certain url that is causing me problems. So far, I have been pulling the shortcode from a url like so:

```
const instagramRegex = /https:\/\/www.instagram.com\/p\/([\w-]+)\/?/g;
let shortcode = instaRegex.exec(url)[1];
```

This returns the shortcode as expected, something that looks like BU89NChA8Cz from a url like https://www.instagram.com/p/BU89NChA8Cz/. The problem now is, the following url returns html, not a json response as expected. It is also not likely a shortcode.

**Problem url:** https://www.instagram.com/p/BTC-qwADp7WmlJ06W_Z_B59Bxbpml31t_fb-3U0/

The regex still returns the "shortcode" as expected: BTC-qwADp7WmlJ06W_Z_B59Bxbpml31t_fb-3U0, but this is not what I want as it is a "Page Not Found" HTML doc, not an api response.

I have also tried variations of this larger code, splitting on "_", but each of those returns "invalid media id"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is an invalid link. Why do you expect to get anything useful at all?

Comment: It is not invalid. Opening the url in a browser directs to the image page, so I expect the usual useful data to be returned . What's invalid about it?

Comment: When I open the URL in my browser, it says "Sorry, this page isn't available."

Comment: This page is definitely available, it is on my own account https://www.instagram.com/p/BTC-qwADp7WmlJ06W_Z_B59Bxbpml31t_fb-3U0/?taken-by=johnmcguirk1981

Comment: You probably have to be logged in as you to access it, then.

Comment: That poses another question then. If I am using an access_token with public level access and the post is not private, why would I need to be logged in?

Comment: That's not the case for the URL in question. The linked URL appears to be private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a URL from a private profile, so you cannot view it.

Usually if the shortcode is that long it is from a Instagram user that is private, that URL will work if you are allowed by that user and you are logged into instagram.com

Comment: Thanks krisrak. Were you able to find official documentation detailing this from Instagram? I'd like to be able to read up on this further to get around the issue, as I do not see how so many clients have suddenly gone private, so maybe my access token is the issue leading to this.

Comment: I just know it from experience, if u look at image link from any of private user on your feed, it will have long short code and cannot be opened in if you are logged out.

Comment: So here is the odd part. If I access my own Instagram account via web, it is not possible to set the privacy status of posts. However, if I access via Android app, I can set my account to Public there. The problem persists, so can it still be thought of as a private post issue?